# Two blocks of text in one row without using tables

Tags: html, css

How can I lay the text out by using just CSS and without using a table?

[image]

My attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/qmhxbsvv/

```css
.first {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.second {
  margin-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <p class='first'>first</p>
  <p class='second'>
    Take Canada's Northwest Territories. You can vicariously poke around the funky capital, Yellowknife. You can click through the two main bush-breaching highways, see the igloo church in Inuvik, and find where the camera car got lost and turned around at
    a hunting shack. There's even a photo of stray dogs near the overgrown gas-stop of Enterprise, fitting but random.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: what have you tried? I would recommend looking into `position:absolute`, or `float:left` or `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since flex-box doesn't have great legacy support, here is a solution to your question using only a simple float.

The first item is simply floated left.

```css
p {
  margin:0;
}

.first {
  font-weight: bold;
  float:left;
}

.second {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.row {
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <p class='first'>first</p>
  <p class='second'>
    Take Canada's Northwest Territories. You can vicariously poke around the funky capital, Yellowknife. You can click through the two main bush-breaching highways, see the igloo church in Inuvik, and find where the camera car got lost and turned around at
    a hunting shack. There's even a photo of stray dogs near the overgrown gas-stop of Enterprise, fitting but random.
  </p>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <p class='first'>first</p>
  <p class='second'>
    Take Canada's Northwest Territories. You can vicariously poke around the funky capital, Yellowknife. You can click through the two main bush-breaching highways, see the igloo church in Inuvik, and find where the camera car got lost and turned around at
    a hunting shack. There's even a photo of stray dogs near the overgrown gas-stop of Enterprise, fitting but random.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using flexbox would be the easiest I think.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.first {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.second {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <p class='first'>first</p>
  <p class='second'>
    Take Canada's Northwest Territories. You can vicariously poke around the funky capital, Yellowknife. You can click through the two main bush-breaching highways, see the igloo church in Inuvik, and find where the camera car got lost and turned around at
    a hunting shack. There's even a photo of stray dogs near the overgrown gas-stop of Enterprise, fitting but random.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are likely several solutions, such as `display:table-cell`, but I would suggest you to google Flexbox.

Here's a [suggested article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

add `float: left` to `.first` class.

```css
.first {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.second {
  margin-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <p class='first'>first</p>
  <p class='second'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec consectetur leo et lectus sollicitudin pharetra. Cras a sapien id est facilisis rutrum non id augue. Fusce suscipit volutpat libero, vitae vulputate neque dictum non. Nullam vel congue libero, vel auctor magna. Suspendisse commodo sem at dapibus efficitur. Ut metus nisl, consectetur eu quam sit amet, ornare condimentum felis. Donec dapibus sapien consectetur est blandit fringilla. Proin eu est at lacus tempor tincidunt eget at ante. Mauris in nisl at nulla auctor pulvinar.
  </p>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <p class='first'>second</p>
  <p class='second'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec consectetur leo et lectus sollicitudin pharetra. Cras a sapien id est facilisis rutrum non id augue. Fusce suscipit volutpat libero, vitae vulputate neque dictum non. Nullam vel congue libero, vel auctor magna. Suspendisse commodo sem at dapibus efficitur. Ut metus nisl, consectetur eu quam sit amet, ornare condimentum felis. Donec dapibus sapien consectetur est blandit fringilla. Proin eu est at lacus tempor tincidunt eget at ante. Mauris in nisl at nulla auctor pulvinar.
  </p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/49uwm8qz/

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox to the rescue. Here is an updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qmhxbsvv/2/.

[image]

#### CSS

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.first {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 50px;
}
.second {
  flex: 1;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class='row'>
  <p class='first'>first</p>
  <p class='second'>
    Take Canada's Northwest Territories. You can vicariously poke around the funky capital, Yellowknife. You can click through the two main bush-breaching highways, see the igloo church in Inuvik, and find where the camera car got lost and turned around at
    a hunting shack. There's even a photo of stray dogs near the overgrown gas-stop of Enterprise, fitting but random.
  </p>
</div>
```